# Another apparmor / mysql wont install

Tags: mysql, apparmor

I am trying to config another instance of mysql on my present but i can't

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2


Installing MySQL system tables...
ERROR: 1005  Can't create table 'db' (errno: 13)
121118 15:25:12 [ERROR] Aborting

121118 15:25:12 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete


Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/var/lib/mysql2/ for more information.

You can try to start the mysqld daemon with:

    shell> /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant &

and use the command line tool /usr/bin/mysql
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

    shell> /usr/bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using --log
gives you a log in /var/lib/mysql2/ that may be helpful.

Please consult the MySQL manual section
'Problems running mysql_install_db', and the manual section that
describes problems on your OS.  Another information source are the
MySQL email archives available at http://lists.mysql.com/.

Please check all of the above before mailing us!  And remember, if
you do mail us, you MUST use the /usr/scripts/mysqlbug script!
```

syslog::

```
 kernel: [ 6723.794523] type=1400 audit(1353231920.455:324): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=6840 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/var/lib/mysql2/mysql/db.frm" pid=6879 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=115 ouid=115
```

Below is the config:

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor
# Last Modified: Tue Jun 19 17:37:30 2007
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/sbin/mysqld {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/nameservice>
  #include <abstractions/user-tmp>
  #include <abstractions/mysql>
  #include <abstractions/winbind>

  capability dac_override,
  capability sys_resource,
  capability setgid,
  capability setuid,

  network tcp,

  /etc/hosts.allow r,
  /etc/hosts.deny r,

  /etc/mysql/*.pem r,
  /etc/mysql/conf.d/ r,
  /etc/mysql/conf.d/* r,
  /etc/mysql/*.cnf r,
  /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ r,
  /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/*.so* mr,
  /usr/sbin/mysqld mr,
  /usr/share/mysql/** r,
  /var/log/mysql.log rw,
  /var/log/mysql.err rw,
  /var/lib/mysql/ r,
  /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
  /var/log/mysql/ r,
  /var/log/mysql/* rw,
  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid w,
  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,
  /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid w,
  /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,


  /var/log/mysql2.log rw,
  /var/log/mysql2.err rw,
  /var/lib/mysql2/ r,
  /var/lib/mysql2/* rw,
  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid w,
  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.sock w,
  /run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid w,
  /run/mysqld/mysqld2.sock w,

  /sys/devices/system/cpu/ r,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  #include <local/usr.sbin.mysqld>
}
```